# How to force ComboBox to scroll to top?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a winforms **ToolStripComboBox** with a ComboBox property. By default, it seems to auto-scroll to the selected index. See screenshot below:

[image]

On form load, I'm setting SelectedIndex to 1, which is what needs to happen. But I want the first item in the list (SelectedIndex 0) to be visible, or in other words auto-scroll to the very top. I can't find any way to force the combobox to scroll to the top by default, or to do so programmatically. There is an `AutoScrollOffset` property on ComboBox which I have experimented with, but it seems to do nothing, no matter what I set it to.

As seen in my screenshot above, I want to force the combobox (either via property or method call) to appear like the 2nd pic in which the top item (*All - All Categories*) is visible, while still leaving index 1 selected.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the dropdown, a [`LB_SETTOPINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761356) message will be sent to the list which is in the dropdown menu. This message is responsible to setting the top index in the list.

You can handle this message and change its `WParam` to `Intptr.Zero` to always use `0` as top index.

**Native Methods**

Here is a class which contains native methods, structures and constants to manipulate the combo box for this purpose:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class NativeMethods
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left; public int Top; public int Right; public int Bottom;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);
    public class ListBoxHelper : NativeWindow
    {
        private const int LB_SETTOPINDEX = 0x0197;
        public ListBoxHelper(IntPtr hwnd) { this.AssignHandle(hwnd); }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == LB_SETTOPINDEX)
                m.WParam = IntPtr.Zero;
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

**ComboBox**

Here is a `ComboBox` which its dropdown always opens showing item 0 as top item:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    NativeMethods.ListBoxHelper listBoxHelper;
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        var info = new NativeMethods.COMBOBOXINFO();
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        NativeMethods.GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref info);
        listBoxHelper = new NativeMethods.ListBoxHelper(info.hwndList);
    }
}
```

**ToolStripComboBox**

`ToolStripComboBox` hosts a `ComboBox` inside. So the solution is similar:

```
public class MyToolStripComboBox : ToolStripComboBox
{
    public MyToolStripComboBox()
    {
        this.Control.HandleCreated += Control_HandleCreated;
    }
    NativeMethods.ListBoxHelper listBoxHelper;
    private void Control_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        var info = new NativeMethods.COMBOBOXINFO();
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        NativeMethods.GetComboBoxInfo(this.Control.Handle, ref info);
        listBoxHelper = new NativeMethods.ListBoxHelper(info.hwndList);
    }
}
```